# Find row with exact matching with the string i wanted using CONTAINS

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have a dataframe below, I wanted to find all name contain 'And'

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Andrew", "Jen And Jess"," Gin And]})
```

my code
`df[df["name"].str.contains('AND',na=False)]`

My code's output included with substring and consist 'And'

What i expecting:

```
name
Jen And Jess
Gin And
```

Comment: Can you do `.contains(' AND ', na=False)` (with spacings)?

Comment: I tried, no row returns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To catch upper and lower, you can do:

```
import re
df[df["name"].str.contains(r'\b[Aa][Nn][Dd]\b')]
```

Answer (score 0):

use regex in the contain and surround the 'And' with the \b (word boundaries)
you can use IGNORECASE flag, to keep the pattern simple

```
import re

df[df.name.str.contains(r'\band\b', flags=re.IGNORECASE , regex=True)]
```

```
name
1   Jen And Jess
2   Gin And
```